# question regarding closure of symmetric neighborhood of e

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

I was going through the open mapping theorem (for topological groups) when I stumbled upon a topological property that I couldn't prove to myself.
If I have a topological group, $G$ which is $\sigma$-compact and locally compact, then for every $U=U^{-1}$, a symmetric neighborhood of $e$, there is a precompact neighborhood $V=V^{-1}$ of $e$. Moreover, $V$ can be chosen so that if $W=\overline{V}$ is the closure of $V$, then

> $$W^{-1}W\subseteq U.$$

I know I can always find a $V$ as mentioned, but I don't know the reason why its closure should be compact or why the above multiplication should work for the closures.
Any help to shed light will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You do more or less the same thing as proving the initial $V$ exists, it's just a slight modification. Select a pre-compact neighborhood $V'$ of $e$. Then consider $V''=V'\cap U$. Symmetrizing $V''$ by examining $V_0=V''\cap (V'')^{-1}$, we can see that $V_0$ is pre-compact and symmetric since it is contained in $W'$.

Now for containment in $U$ we do the same trick as we do for the original $V$, we find another neighborhood $V_1$ such that $V_1^2\subseteq U$ and set

$$V=V_0\cap (V_1\cap V_1^{-1}).$$

This is still obviously symmetric (that's why I put the parentheses in the intersection) and pre-compact--the closure is a closed subset of $\overline{V'}$ which is compact--and such that $VV^{-1}\subseteq U$--since

$$VV^{-1}=V^2\subseteq V_1^2\subseteq U.$$

Comment: thanks, another question if I may. How do I know that a subset of a precompact is still precompact?

Comment: @AvivEshed because the space is Hausdorff (in fact normal) you know that closed subsets of compact sets are compact. So since precompact means "has a compact closure" you get the result.

Comment: But what makes our space Hausdorff? All we know it is regular.

Comment: @AvivEshed homogeneous spaces are completely regular, hence Hausdorff.

Comment: Although this is five years old, I'd just like to point out for future readers that the space need not be Hausdorff in order for $V_0$ to be precompact. A closed subset of a compact set is compact in _any_ topological space, regardless of Hausdorffness.